# Shared Preference issue in Android App

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

in my app i have three activities named as Home, SignIn and Add Page.

In my home Screen i have declared the Shared preference as follows

```
   Idprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   int UserId = Idprefs.getInt("useridValue", 0);
```

If UserId ==0 i goes to SignIn Activity or else to AddPage

In my SignIn Activity the user has to enter the name and password, from the server i get back an id in an xml file, which i am parsing and storing it the shared preference.

To use this value in other activities i have declared it as follows

```
public static SharedPreferences Idprefs;
```

in my oncreate method i have this

```
Idprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

from my parsed values i am storing in Shared preference

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Idprefs.edit();
editor.putInt("useridValue", userid);
editor.commit();
```

In my third Activity i have the following

```
int User = SignIn.Idprefs.getInt("useridValue",0);
```

here i am using the User value for other purposes.

Now the problem is all the above said functions work proper for the first time when the app i launched ie it will go as

```
HomeScreen--> SignIn --> AddPage
```

But when the app closed and opened for the second time the flow is as follows

```
HomeScreen --> AddPage
```

Now the app is getting crashed and i logcat it refers to the following line in AddPage Activity

```
 int User = SignIn.Idprefs.getInt("useridValue",0);
```

Second time SignIn page is not called so that it gets crashed. How can i get the stored value in other activities, pleas help me

Comment: Well can you paste the DDMS logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the preferences through a class that was not instantiated (SignIn):

```
int User = SignIn.Idprefs.getInt("useridValue",0);
```

And therefore it's probably `NULL`.

It's a bad practice to access class members (especially when context is involved) this way. Just instantiate them each time in your current activity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing shared preferences after the super.onCreate() call in your activity?  Otherwise, this will throw errors and cause the application to malfunction.